# Visual Studio mac, how to debug client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying Visual Studio Community for Mac, release April 2017 (not Visual Studio Code,) and can't get the client side Javascript debugger to work.
dotnet core C# backend debug works fine, but front-end javascript breakpoints are ignored.
Using Safari as browser and launching debug with alt-enter or Run/Start Debugging.

Thanks!

Comment: Almost 2 years later, now VS 2019 for Mac and it appears JS debugging still isn't possible. The only work-around I'm aware of is use something like the Chrome debugger (right-click > Inspect > Sources tab) and set breakpoints there